# Malady vs Disease

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, metaphors

How  does the word malady differ from disease? Also,in what contexts can the word malady be used?

Below are my findings / details I have collected  about the two:

1. Many dictionaries list the word malady as old fashioned. (but not always)

2.Disease is a term  frequently used by medical professionals. But, I almost never see the word malady used in  medical fields in the same sense. So, my educated guess is DISEASE has a strict medical definition.  it is A MEDICAL CONDITION (involving its laboratory finding definite causes symptoms and cure).

3.In every day english, illness reflects how one feels about her/ himself eg:- I'm feeling ill / not well coz I got a headache.the sufferer needn't have a  medical condition to just  feel ill.  So, an ill guy can stay without a disease!  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disease

4. Similarly, sickness reflects how long a person is bed ridden / absent from his job eg:- he reported sick leave today.  The words illness and sickness are less stigmatizing than disease. So, my gut-feeling is that the word malady can perhaps have similar connotations too.

5.Though considered old fashioned, malady is still used to refer to  PROBLEMS IN GENERAL or CHRONIC/ SERIOUS/ DEEP- SEATED DISEASES eg:- 1.the monthly malady of ladies ( menses?) 2. Cure for certain maladies like cancer.... 3. Homelessness is a social malody (https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/malady

6.Though considered non- medical, the word still appears in medical literature. eg:- "sexually transmitted melody" meaning that it is not completely obsolete
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuxmq.jpg

Comment: Have you checked their definitions?

Comment: malady is not used much in contemporary speech. That said there is a lovely book called: The Interpreter of Maladies by Jhumpa Lahiri. It's similar to journey for trip. Somewhat literary.

Comment: I use *malady* as metaphor for vague but chronic faults: Cheapness, being on automatic, learned helplessness of asking for help in googling.

Comment: I note that the author of (5) has an Indian name. In British English _malady_ sounds old-fashioned and is used more in the metaphorical sense - 'a social malady' - than to refer to an actual disease.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I said that and got two downvotes. In AmE it is also old fashioned. And the book I cited is a **novel** by an Indian author living in the US.

Comment: @jsw29 The only difference is that the term is old fashioned. Otherwise, a malady is a sickness or a disease. It is the same thing originally.

Answer (score -2):

malady is not used much in contemporary, ordinary speech.

That said there is a lovely book called: The Interpreter of Maladies by Jhumpa Lahiri. It's similar to journey for trip. Somewhat literary. And quite 19th c.

A malady is a sickness, i.e. disease. Same thing.

Comment: Subtle difference exists among the words sickness illness disease and malady.

Comment: No, a malady is a sickness or a disease or an illness. The word is not common today except in literature. Synonyms: ailment, disease, disorder, distemper, illness, sickness.https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malady

Comment: @Lambie When a word is uncommon except in literature, I would agree with OP it creates a subtle difference. It probably has literary register, which adds a sense of formality or high culture. For example, in a novel having a modern setting, if a character uses the word "malady" it could create the sense that the character is bookish, or affects bookishness. There is a world of difference between a synonym and a strict equality.

Comment: @MetaEd Where have I not basically said that in my answer? I said it was literary, I said it was 19 c. and I even gave a literary title to show how it is used. There is no difference: Shakespeare's King Lear: **that this contentious storm
Invades us to the skin. So 'tis to thee;
But where the greater malady [sickness or desease] is fix'd,
The lesser is scarce felt** Same thing.

Comment: @Lambie You said "a malady", "a sickness", and "disease" are the same, and when Selfie groupie pointed out a subtle difference exists among the words "sickness", "illness", "disease", and "malady", you said no, they are the same. And that's the part of your answer, and the part of your comment, that I don't agree with. And I don't think you agree with yourself either, because you pointed out there is a difference of register.

Comment: @MetaEd The difference in register and historical time is about it. I covered that.

Comment: At least, in medical sense the term disease has strict denotative meaning. illness sickness....these words have connotations unlike disease. So should be MALADY which  is mostly old- fashioned though.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disease

Comment: @Selfiegroufie I fail to see what your edit did for the question. And it has a lot of typos and grammar  mistakes. Sure, a social malady as Kate said above. for example. For a medical condition, it is no longer used.

Comment: The fact that *malady* is old fashioned, does subtly influence what it stands for; it does not differ from *disease* merely in register. If somebody nowadays described his condition as a malady, one would be inclined to think that it is a vague feeling of ill-being that does not neatly fit any diagnosis recognised by contemporary medical science.

Comment: True true.... I speak the same language.

Comment: @jsw29 As I said, the term malady is not used by people today to refer to what ails them unless the person is particularly literary, which is entirely possible. Just like ailment. There is just not that much more to say about the term.

Comment: Someone upvoted me but there are still two negative votes. Ha ha.